# Grails/groovy testing - any difference between assert and assertEquals methods

Tags: java, grails, groovy, junit

I have numerous Grails unit and integration groovy test classes.

Originally I used methods such as assertEquals, assertNull, assertTrue, assertFalse, etc.

```
assertEquals 0, User.list().size()
```

but recently I've been preferring to use a straight assert:

```
assert User.list().size() == 0
```

Is there any difference between these 2 approaches?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `assertEquals` is using a JUnit assertion, whereas the `assert` is using groovy's *power assert*. The power assert gives you much nicer error messages and is built-in to the language. You should generally use that one when you can.

Comment: does "assert" want the EXPECTED on the left side or right side?  or does it matter?  (Where assertEquals it is labeled which is which)

Answer (score 2):

An `AssertionError` is thrown in case `assertEquals` fails but no such error is thrown in case when `assert` is used but it does a power assert in groovy and provides good assertion messages when fails.